# Sorting content of text file by number

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have a text file that contain data like:

> 12, abcd
>
> 2541, sdfrhk
>
> 4, qwerty
>
> 13, uytrew
>
> 345, iuoiyt

How can I sort content by number in descending order? Preferably using batch. Thanks

Comment: As dbenham says, why not use script?

Answer (score 5):

You can't sort it directly. The only batch solution I can think of is to parse and recreate each line with the number prefixed with zeros to a constant width. Once the numbers have a fixed width, you can use SORT to create a new sorted file, and then one more FOR /F to strip off the leading zeros.

I'll assume 15 digits is enough for the largest number. This solution assumes all the numbers are integers greater than 0.

```
@echo off
set "file=test.txt"
>"%file%.new1" (
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=," %%A in ("%file%") do (
    set "n=000000000000000%%A"
    set "str=%%B"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo !n:~-15!,!str!
    endlocal
  )
)
>"%file%.new2" sort /r "%file%.new1"
>"%file%" (
  for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=0" %%A in ("%file%.new2") do echo %%A
)
del "%file%.new?"
```

Additional work must be done in the final step if 0 is a value in the original file. Even more work must be done throughout the script if negative numbers are allowed.

You could write a much more efficient script using VBScript or JavaScript.

Comment: That the numbers are supposed to be integers seems to be bound to go without saying. Still, I ventured to put it explicitly in your answer, in the hope you wouldn't mind. :)

Comment: @AndriyM - Can't argue with that :-)

Comment: Thanks guys - this works but extremely slow. Test.txt with 20 rows this bat file proceeded about 2 minutes. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Gabil - Hey, I know batch text processing is relatively slow, which is why I said you could write a more efficient script using VBS. But 2 minutes for 20 rows???? Something is wrong with your machine. I just used this script to process a 61,485 byte file containing 1572 lines in just over 1 second.

Comment: EDIT - I fixed the sort to be descending, I missed that requirement when I first read the question.

Comment: @dbenham - I know that you're redirecting streams here, but could you put some comments in for a fogie like me who never really got much beyond `2>&1`.

Comment: @dbenham - Also, I see you're using 0's as delimiters. Won't that cause trouble with any numbers that actually contain 0's? Like 107 and such. Or, actually, what's the point of delimiters with `tokens=*`?

Comment: @JamesK - The redirection is pretty much vanilla. You can put the redirection anywhere in the command; I chose to put it at the beginning. I redirected the entire FOR block within parentheses because it is more efficient (faster) to redirect only once instead of redirecting each iteration of the FOR loop. The `TOKENS=*` preserves the entire line remaining after leading delimiters are stripped - in this case stripping leading zeros.

Answer (score 3):

VBScript example using a disconnected [recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Not necessarily less code, but *a lot* easier to maintain.

```
Const ForReading = 1

Const adInteger = 3
Const adVarChar = 200
Const maxChars  = 255

Const sep = ", "

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set data = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
data.Fields.Append "num", adInteger
data.Fields.Append "txt", adVarChar, maxChars
data.Open

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("INPUT.TXT", ForReading)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  values = Split(f.ReadLine, sep, 2)
  data.AddNew
  data("num").Value = CInt(values(0))
  data("txt").Value = values(1)
  data.Update
Loop
f.Close

data.Sort = "num DESC"

data.MoveFirst
Do Until data.EOF
  WScript.Echo data("num") & sep & data("txt")
  data.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thanks for quick reply. I understood this code takes input from Input.txt file. But what about output? Where can I see sorted strings? I have run this script but with no change. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Gabil Right now it's just echoing the output. If you want it written to a file instead, simply use the [`WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5399c99%28v=vs.84%29) method. The recordset is sorted by the instruction `data.Sort = "num DESC"`. If you want just the strings without the numbers, output only `data("txt")` instead of `data("num") & sep & data("txt")`.

Comment: You can use the script as is and just redirect the output in your batch file like this, `CSCRIPT Sorter.vbs >SortedText.txt`.

Comment: +1, but you should add the count parameter to Split in case the string contains the delimiter: `Split(f.ReadLine, sep, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Originally I wasn't going to post this because it seemed a repeat of dbenham's answer, but a closer look made me realize that it's not really the same (meaning I don't understand much of his) so here's mine, and "nearly" the same size too!  (Ok! It's like a third longer than his, sue me. ^_^)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set source=sortme.txt
set tsort=sortme.tmp
set size=0
set zeros=
:: Pass 1
for /f "tokens=1 delims=, " %%x in (sort.txt) do (
   set num=%%x
   call strlen num tsize
   if !tsize! gtr !size! set size=!tsize!
)
for /l %%c in (1,1,%size%) do set zeros=!zeros!0
:: Pass 2
for /f "tokens=1* delims=, " %%x in (sort.txt) do (
  set line=%zeros%%%x
  set line=!line:~-%size%!
  echo !line! %%x, %%y>> sort.tmp
)
endlocal
del sort.txt > nul
:: Pass 3
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%x in ('sort /r sort.tmp') do echo %%y>>sort.txt
del sort.tmp > nul
```

It takes three passes at the data, before it's finished, so it could probably be paired down some.

It also takes advantage of [STRLEN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#strLen) from [DOStips.com](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#strLen)

Answer (score 1):

A variation of [@dbenham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12341450/43774) can be used to sort the file much faster, completely within memory, without any temporary files, without the need of `sort`, and without changing the text of the input.

The caveat is that the file must be small enough that it's contents and this algorithm stay within the 32kb environment memory limit (see [environment memory limits](https://superuser.com/a/1070354/15803)).

Again, as in @dbenham's answer, this algorithm expects positive integer numbers, no larger than 15 digits in size.

```
:: sort-file.BAT
@setlocal
@echo off
set args=%*
if NOT DEFINED args (echo usage: %~dp0 FILE_TO_SORT & exit /b 1)
::
set file=%~1
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%file%") do (
    set line=%%A
    for /f "delims=, tokens=1,*" %%G in ("%%A") do (
        set normalized_number=00000000000000%%G
        call set _line_%%normalized_number:~-15%%=%%line%%
        )
    )
for /f "delims== tokens=1,*" %%A in ( 'set _line_' ) do (
    echo %%B
    )
::
```